# 500 Error with no details on site migration

Tags: error-message, craft3, environments

I'm trying to migrate my site from a PHP5.6 host to a PHP 7 host in preparation for Craft 3.

I've copied everything across and am trying to load an exact copy of the production site on a different domain to see if it's all working as expected.

Unfortunately I don't make it far.
On hitting the site I get:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function run() on integer in /blah.com.au/htdocs/craft/app/index.php:62

Stack trace:
#0 /blah.com.au/htdocs/public/index.php(19): require_once()
#1 {main}
thrown in /blah.com.au/htdocs/craft/app/index.php on line 62
```

There are no other details anywhere.
To avoid cache issues I've also done a fresh upload of Craft and then copied across my config, templates, plugins, public directories etc.
Exact same error.

I've updated the config files (db/general) to have the correct paths for this new domain. The database is the same as production.

my .htaccess shouldn't be causing issues.

Any ideas peoples?

Comment: I think I might've seen this when a line within one of my own plugins was failing after migrating to a server that didn't support said line. Something like that. Can you uninstall your plugins and install them again one at a time?

Comment: Thanks @ClivePortman it actually turns out my MySQL wasn't installed properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out my MySQL wasn't installed correctly.
I'm using RDS but my setup didn't meet the basic requirements to connect to it from PHP.

Comment: Hey Trev Dev, thanks for following up and posting an answer. Don't forget to accept it and score some extra points!

Comment: Could you share a little more about what the problem was with MySQL? I'm getting this same issue.