# 500 Error on AWS bitnami instance

Tags: error-message, install, aws

I have a fresh LAMP instance based on a bitnami image on AWS. All server requirements are met for Craft 2, but I'm getting a 500 error when trying to hit the site:

> site.com is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Seeing this in the error log:

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function run() on integer

I've done separate db tests for pdo and mysqli -- connectivity seems fine. Permissions all look correct (774). Any thoughts on what could be causing?

Comment: No idea, but there is a similar question here that might help: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/19332/500-error-with-no-details-on-site-migration

Comment: Thanks Brad.  I think we tracked it down -- will post a separate reply describing the fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, turns out the issue was with the `$app = require 'bootstrap.php';` line in app/index.php.  There was another directory for smarty template engine that was getting pulled from for the bootstrap file.  After removing that conflicting file, the issue was resolved.  Strange issue, but hopefully can help if anyone bumps into this in the future...