# bootstrap.php returns a value of 1 in Craft CMS

Tags: craft2

I have a Craft CMS instance that I created a copy of by tarring up the folder and then dumping the mysql database and then transferring that to a different server. On the target server I restored the folder and the database.  When I attempt to access the instance, I get an error in the Apache logs:

```
[Mon Jul 29 15:48:01.415795 2019] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function run() on integer in /var/www/html/bsf_public/craft/app/index.php:73\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/bsf_public/public/index.php(19): require_once()\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/bsf_public/craft/app/index.php on line 73\n'
```

I have spent multiple hours chasing the errors.  A phpinfo() call in a file works so I know that PHP is properly configured.  So I focused on line 73 of the index.php file referenced in the error message.  It has these lines (in addition to others):

```
// Load and run Craft
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

$app = require 'bootstrap.php';
$app->run();
```

$app is returning a value of 1.  bootstrap.php has these final lines of code:

```
$appClass = '\Craft\WebApp';
$app = new $appClass($config);

return $app;
```

I can't quite figure out why the bootstrap.php is returning a 1 which is why the error message occurs.  I found one other instance of this being reported in a PHP app but the post had no resolution.

Maybe a Craft CMS guru can point me the right direction although I'll bet it is some kind of permissions or PHP issue.  I checked the PHP files and they all have execute permissions.

Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS

5.7.26 MySQL

PHP 7.1.29 (cli) (built: May  3 2019 09:33:57) ( NTS )

Craft CMS 2.7.5

Comment: There's a couple of other similar posts here that might help? https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/19332/500-error-with-no-details-on-site-migration and https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/26499/500-error-on-aws-bitnami-instance

Comment: Thanks Brad...not sure how I missed those in my search.  They point directly to the problem and environment.  Wish I had seen them.  I decided the Bitnami LAMP stack was the issue and downgraded to version 5 stack that installed PHP 5.6 (in particular). That fixed it although I am intrigued by the later posted you cited.

Answer (score 1):

In my particular case, I downgraded the Bitnami LAMP stack using instructions found here: https://community.bitnami.com/t/how-can-i-downgrade-to-php-5-6-from-php-7-0/51792

The downgrade fixed the issue although, had I seen Brad's answer before that, no doubt I could have fixed it using those posts....